# How to prevent XSS in PHP, when need to parse dirty markdown to clean markdown content

Tags: php, laravel, markdown, xss, htmlpurifier

Non English native.

### What is my code:

`File create.blade.php`

```html
<textarea> dirty markdown content </textarea> 
<preview> marked.js parsed html </preview>
<!-- this is a markdown editor, it can parse markdown to html using marked.js-->
<!-- then show in preview -->
<!-- something like stackoverflow editor does -->
<!-- when user edit done. post dirty markdown data to BlogController@create -->
```

---

`File edit.blade.php`

```html
<textarea> parsed clean markdown content from backend </textarea>
<preview> clean parsed html</preview>
```

---

`File BlogController.php`

```php
<?php
// get editor data from create.blade.php
// parse markdown content to prevent XSS
// save cleaned markdown content to DB
function create() {}

// get clean markdown data from DB
// return cleaned markdown content to edit.blade.php
function edit() {}
```

### Stuck at the step

I'm stuck at this step: `dirty markdown content` <-- parse in PHP --> `cleaned markdown content`

### What I tried

I have tried: [parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown), [commonmark](https://github.com/thephpleague/commonmark) [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)
But I couldn't separate the library.
Such as commonmark, it seems like
`Dirty markdown content` <--> `Dirty AST tree` <---> `AST to HTML(with parse)`
I thought the step of `AST to HTML(with parse)` is so difficult to me to separate as parts of `AST tree` <--> `parsed AST tree` <--> `Cleaned markdown content`

And the HTMLPurifier will parse all content, even the `script` tags surrounded by ```:
Before

````
```html
some text
<script> some js code </script>
some text
```
````

After using HTMLPurifier, it return

````
```html
some text
some text
```
````

the script tags has gone.

### What I expect

Some libraries who can parse `dirty markdown content` to `cleaned markdown content`

ps: I'm using laravel 7.*, marked.js, MySQL.
pps: Thanks for reading, and thanks for any suggestions.

### Updated

What I expect is:
User edit dirty markdown -> `clean dirty markdown -> cleaned markdown ->` save to DB -> return cleaned markdown content -> user edit -> ...

But maybe there is another way could done this job:
User edit dirty markdown -> `CommonMark -> cleaned HTML -> HTML to Markdown ->` save to DB -> return cleaned markdown content -> user edit -> ...

Comment: Hey @Samtoo did you check this `https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier`

Comment: Thx for ur reply @ChintanKotadiya Yeap, checked. Does HTMLPurifier can ignore `script` tags which in ``` ?

Comment: Hey @Samtoo here is an full document of Purifier configuration. please go through this once. `http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.SafeScripting` hope this will help

Comment: HTML Purifier is a HTML parser - if you feed it markdown, expect it to do strange things! :) "There is _some_ HTML in the Markdown" doesn't make the Markdown document HTML, which is why you're seeing `<script>` removed. It's best if you view HTML Purifier as an _output_ handler - you would apply it to _rendered_ Markdown.

Comment: In other words, your workflow would be like this: Let people input whatever they want into the text area. Save that in the database without tampering. Let them edit it in the form they've supplied it (_no cleaning_). But when you output what's in the database as HTML (e.g. as a preview), apply HTML Purifier.

Comment: @pinkgothic That's an awesome idea! Thanks a lot!